# Unary + on pointers

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading

I was just browsing through the [draft of the C++11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf) and found the following puzzling statement (§13.6/8):

> For every type `T` there exist candidate operator functions of the form
>
> ```
> T* operator+(T*);
> ```

How should this "unary +" operator on pointer be understood? Is this just a no-op in the normal case, which can nevertheless be overloaded? Or is there some deeper point I am missing here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer to your question is just a page above the quote you cited — §13.6/1:

> The candidate operator functions that represent the built-in operators defined in Clause 5 are specified in this subclause. **These candidate functions participate in the operator overload resolution process as described in 13.3.1.2 and are used for no other purpose.** [ *Note:* Because built-in operators take only operands with non-class type, and operator overload resolution occurs only when an operand expression originally has class or enumeration type, operator overload resolution can resolve to a built-in operator only when an operand has a class type that has a user-defined conversion to a non-class type appropriate for the operator, or when an operand has an enumeration type that can be converted to a type appropriate for the operator. Also note that some of the candidate operator functions given in this subclause are more permissive than the built-in operators themselves. As described in 13.3.1.2, after a built-in operator is selected by overload resolution the expression is subject to the requirements for the built-in operator given in Clause 5, and therefore to any additional semantic constraints given there. If there is a user-written candidate with the same name and parameter types as a built-in candidate operator function, the built-in operator function is hidden and is not included in the set of candidate functions. *—end note* ]

Comment: So `T* operator+(T*);` is member or global one? and in the case of lambda -> `+[]{};` what is `T` I wonder? Thanks

Comment: @AngelusMortis : Pointers cannot have members; this uses the language's builtin unary `operator+` for arithmetic types. And the type of `+[]{}` is `void(*)()`, as unary `operator+` on captureless lambdas converts the lambda into a function pointer.

Comment: Dear sir, I'm still little confused, so lemme ask by quoting your statements -> "Pointers cannot have members" yes but I had initially thought lambdas get converted to class types (by compilers) overloading  `operator()`, hence I thought they could be member. Now your statement "this uses the language's builtin unary `operator+` for arithmetic types" , I'm sure arithmetic types are basically integral+float types, then how the expression -> `+[]()` -> `operator+(some_unknown_type_I_don't_know)` -> gets converted to `void(*)()`

Comment: @AngelusMortis : Sorry, I didn't know you were **only** asking about lambdas; the OP's question is about pointers, and pointers are scalar types. Lambdas with captures do not have any operators other than `operator()`, but _captureless_ lambdas are also implicitly convertible to function pointers, so unary `operator+` forces this conversion. (`+` on any lambdas with captures would fail to compile.)

Comment: That means there is overloaded `operator+(void(*)())` is present ?, but doesn't that creates another problem? I mean there could be infinite function signatures, how does single `operator+` would handle all function pointers? . Is unary `operator+` is template? I'm soo confused :( Thanks . And my sincere apologies for hijacking the thread :(

Comment: @AngelusMortis : No, on captureless lambdas there is an `operator function_pointer_type`; the lambda has no `operator+` so using `+` on the lambda calls _that_ operator and applies `+` to the resulting pointer.

Answer (score 10):

The `+` on pointers is a noop except for turning things to rvalues. It sometimes is handy if you want to decay arrays or functions

```
int a[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
auto &&x = +a;
```

Now `x` is an `int*&&` and not an `int(&)[3]`. If you want to pass `x` or `+a` to templates, this difference might become important. `a + 0` is not always equivalent, consider

```
struct forward_decl;
extern forward_decl a[];
auto &&x = +a; // well-formed
auto &&y = a + 0; // ill-formed
```

The last line is ill-formed, because adding anything to a pointer requires the pointer's pointed-to class type to be completely defined (because it advances by `sizeof(forward_decl) * N` bytes).

Comment: isn't this what `std::move()` and `std::forward()` is meant to do? So if I understand this correctly `+a` and `std::move(a)` would do the same?

Comment: @LiKao not at all. `move` preserves the type, but just changes the value category. So `move(a)` would yield an rvalue of type `int[3]`, not an rvalue of type `int*`. Now applying `move` to a function doesn't do anything at all (casting to `FunctionType&&` yields an lvalue) and isn't particularly meaningful I think.

Comment: @LiKao: No, `std::move` preserves the array, while unary + decays it (and produces an rvalue pointer).

Comment: The most important difference here is that `move` preserves identity: The location that the xvalue result references is still the same as what was put as argument to `move`. However the builtin `+` throws away identity and only preserves the value.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could overload it do do whatever you want, but it's just there for symmetry with the unary - operator.  As you mention, it's just a no-op most of the time.

Comment: could you? _operator must have an argument of class or enumerated type_?