# What is the reason for the existent difference between C and C++ relative to the unary arithmetic operator +

Tags: c++, c, pointers, unary-operator

In C the unary plus operator is called *unary arithmetic operator* and may not be applied to pointers (the C Standard, 6.5.3.3 Unary arithmetic operators).

> 1 The operand of the unary + or - operator **shall have arithmetic
>   type**; of the ~ operator, integer type; of the ! operator, scalar
>   type.

Thus this program will not compile

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int a = 10;
    int *pa = &a;

    printf( "%d\n", *+pa );

    return 0;
}
```

However in C++ the unary plus operator may be applied to pointers (the C++ Standard, 5.3.1 Unary operators)

> 7 The operand of the unary + operator shall have arithmetic, unscoped
>   enumeration, **or pointer type** and the result is the value of the
>   argument. Integral promotion is performed on integral or enumeration
>   operands. The type of the result is the type of the promoted operand.

And this program compiles successfully.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    int a = 10;
    int *pa = &a;

    std::cout << *+pa << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

What is the reason for maintaining this difference between C and C++?

---

The question arose when I was answering the question [Why size of int pointer is different of size of int array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41699762/why-size-of-int-pointer-is-different-of-size-of-int-array/41699896#41699896). I was going to show how to convert an array to a pointer in the `sizeof` operator.

At first I wanted to write

```
sizeof( +array )
```

However this expression is invalid in C. So I had to write

```
sizeof( array + 0 )
```

and I found that there is such a difference between C and C++.:)

Comment: To allow `auto* p = +[](){};` ? ;)

Comment: @Jarod42:  Surely you mean `auto* _ = +[](){};` ?

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9266648/unary-on-pointers

Comment: You can use it to pass value instead of a reference to an overloaded function...

Comment: What output do you expect? For c++ I get 10.

Answer (score 1):

Different languages may attach different semantics to the same syntax.

C and C++ are different languages with a common ancestor. C++ semantics look deceptively similar but are subtly different for some parts of the common syntax. Another curious case is this:

```
if (sizeof(char) == sizeof(int)) {
    printf("Hello embedded world\n");
} else {
    if (sizeof('a') == sizeof(char))
        printf("This is C++ code\n");
    if (sizeof('a') == sizeof(int))
        printf("This is C code\n");
}
```

The reason for C++ to have extended the C syntax in the case of unary `+` might be to allow for some extended numeric types to be implemented as pointers, or simply for reasons of symmetry.

As Jaa-c mentions in a comment, `+p` is a computed expression whereas `p` is a reference to `p`. You provided another example where `+` can be used to force expression context. The question is why did the original authors of the C language disallow unary `+` on non numeric types? Maybe a side effect of the original implementation of `pcc`.

Note that in Javascript, the unary `+` operator can be applied to non number types and operates as a conversion to number.

Answer (score -2):

In my considerations:

C++ is a type of Object-Oriented Language. So every data type can be treated as a "Class".

In C int is one of "the basic data type of C". But in C++ we can consider int as a Class. Thus, In C++ int pointer and int array belong to the different classes. In C a int pointer variable stored another int variable's address. int array's name instead of the first element's address of that int array. So in C they have kind of the same meaning.

As for the unary opreator "+", I understand the C++ language as: Every class In C++ represents a set of stuff. Every stuff in the set has the same properties. And there's some operations can be done onto each stuff. Of course these operations are member functions of a class. Another character In C++ is that users can overload an operator. Overload means we can do the same operation on the different Classes. For example: A man is eating a burger. we can overload action "Eat" between cats and rat: A cat is Eating a rat.

So as the C++ standard say:"**The operand of the unary + operator shall have arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, or pointer type and the result is the value of the argument.**" That's just a overload for unary operator + in Class *unscoped enumeration* and *pointer type*. "**And The Result Is The Value Of The Argument**"-> I guess that's the point.

Comment: `int` is not a class in C++.

Comment: Yeah, but C++ is not a well designed language either. Designers just squeeze lots of new features especially the OOP feature into language C. That's indeed we can not query menber functions of a class int in C++ like: int.what; but it's hard to make a judge that stuff in C represent what in C++. Basically All the stuff in C is a sub-set in C++. If we treat the data-types in C like int, char... as Classes in C++, it's just better for understanding.

Comment: All this waffle is totally and utterly irrelevant. You stated that `int` 'can be considered as a class' in C++. It can't.